# OVH cloud database: how to whiltelist Kubernetes nodepool instead of all node IPs

Tags: database, kubernetes, ovh

The problem is simple: I have an OVH cloud database which I need to access from my Kubernetes cluster.
The cloud database has to whitelist authorized IPs. What I currently do is add each node IP upon creation. This can become tedious to maintain and also poses a problem with auto-scaling, since the created node will not have access the the database until the IP is manually whitelisted.
The official documentation and forum do not indicate how to proceed. It there any way to whitelist the whole cluster?